# TypeError: cv2_imshow() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given : google colab cv related problems

Tags: python, image, opencv, google-colaboratory, imshow

```
visualize_boxes(self, image_name, boxes1, boxes2)
                ........
--->          cv2_imshow("bounding boxes", img)
              #cv2.waitKey(100)
```

at this line it shows `cv2_imshow()` takes 1 positional argument but 2. Earlier I changed `cv2.image` format according to what google colab understands and commented on the `cv2.waitkey()`, is this creating?

Answer (score 1):

No,`cv2.waitkey()` is not causing this. The syntax of `cv2_imshow()` is wrong. You need to do something along the lines of this because cv2_imshow takes only 1 argument:

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
cv2_imshow(img)
```

For further details you can view the official colab advanced output guide [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=zo9YYDL4SYZr).